# How to select a data access database filtering with the months of the date?

Tags: c#, sql, date, ms-access

I want to select the row of a database when the month of a date is accurate. for the year I did it:
`select * from table where YEAR(date)='2015'`  it works well for the years

for the months I made :

```
select * from table where Month(date)='01'// I have the date format dd/mm/yyyy
```

thanks

Comment: What seems to be the problem? I could see one problem. The Month returns an Int and you are comparing it with a String.

Comment: @PaulFrancis I tried with an int is still not working

Comment: Explain not working, Soner has the answer for you ¬

Comment: @user3714770 Can you please explain _not working_ exactly? You get any error message? You get an unexpected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MONTH FUNCTION](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/month.php);

> The Microsoft Access Month function returns the month (a number from 1
>   to 12) given a date value.

You should check it with an integer, not a string like;

```
select * from table where Month(date) = 1
```

Comment: it doesnt working @soner I think the problem comes from the date format I have a date with a dd / mm / yyyy (french format) and I think sql compiles with the format mm / dd / yyyy (English format)

Comment: If you can't do your formula working than do a query just giving the month and see it's format to learn what you need to compare.

Comment: @Soner it works like you said, the problem comes from the variable that is used, I used a string variable in the query thank you so mush

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select * from table where Month(date)='01' and YEAR(date)='2015'
```